# How to add an off-center background to an SVG icon

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG icon in an HTML file and I have been asked to add an "off-center" background. Something similar to [image] but I have no idea neither where to start.

My current code looks like

```
<style>
.icon {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
</style>

<div class='icon'>
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 30 30" style="enable-background:new 0 0 30 30;">...</svg>
</div>
```

Any idea how I can update the `.icon` class to display the background?

Comment: in order to offset a path you can translate it. If this doesn't help please edit your question and add the paths you have.

Comment: can you post full code plz

Comment: You mean I should change the SVG itself?  Since I have multiple icons I’d rather find a solution to add the background without altering the SVG. If that even make sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the svg elements in a div and use a before pseudo element for the offseted "background"

Observation: you can't use a pseudo element on the svg element

```css
div {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  position:relative;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 10px 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  top:6px;
  left:6px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'>
<path d='M0 0h24v24h-24z' fill='none'></path>
<path d='M9 16.17l-4.17-4.17-1.42 1.41 5.59 5.59 12-12-1.41-1.41z'></path>
</svg>
</div>
<div>
<svg width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'>
<path d='M0 0h24v24h-24z' fill='none'></path>
<path d='M18 7l-1.41-1.41-6.34 6.34 1.41 1.41 6.34-6.34zm4.24-1.41l-10.58 10.58-4.18-4.17-1.41 1.41 5.59 5.59 12-12-1.42-1.41zm-21.83 7.82l5.59 5.59 1.41-1.41-5.58-5.59-1.42 1.41z'></path>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for. Cheers.